# Get executing controller and action name in web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to retrieve executing controller and action name in web API? And how can I implement a method to do that for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use action and controller contexts

```
var actionName = this.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
var controllerName= this.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
```